# Haskell package repa-v4l2 depends on a c libary v4l2

Tags: c, haskell, ubuntu

I am trying to install the repa-v4l2 package on Ubuntu linux. 
If I run `sudo cabal install repa-v4l2` I get a missing c library error telling me I am missing the v4l2 library. After some searching I found the library is called `libv4l-0`. I tried to install this library but apt-get told me the package was already installed.

Comment: You need the headers as well. Since you seem to be running Debian or a derivative, look at the package libv4l-dev.

Comment: @gspr That tip worked now the package complies but when it tries to build it fails and I get this warning `Warning: Couldn't figure out LLVM version! Make sure you have installed LLVM` how do i install LLVM?

Comment: This is not really a programming question anymore, but Ubuntu ships various LLVM versions in the packages named "llvm-<version>". Remember that GHC is sometimes picky about which version to use though.

Comment: @gspr what would be a good forum to ask this question in because google isnt being very helpful?

Comment: Try 'ask ubuntu' also on the stackexchange site/app

Comment: @rhubarbdog I disagree with putting this on the ubuntu ask forums because this deals specifically with cabal-instal